# SQL Removing every abbreviated string until a space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got two different values in the same column. 
Example: ColumnName = COUNTY
Example Data: "NSW New South Wales" 
How can I setup an update/replace query to remove NSW abbreviation and the space and have "New South Wales" only? 
I have different abbreviations per County and I'd hate to do a replace function one by one.

Comment: Are abbreviation always 3 letters?

Comment: And are they always there? (Perhaps you should add more sample table data, and the expected result.)

Comment: The max of the abbreviations is 3 letters.

Comment: And no sometimes the column is '' or NULL 
Examples:
      "TAS  Tasmania"
      "NSW  New South Wales"
      "SA  South Australia"

Comment: So the logic would be Where space exists after first 2 or 3 letters on the left side. Replace everything until the space where char.length = 2 or 3.

Comment: Try this  UPDATE `tabl1` SET `col1` = TRIM(REPLACE("NSW New South Wales","NSW", "")) WHERE `col1` LIKE 'NSW%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) with `REPLACE()`

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET t.YourColumn = LTRIM(REPLACE(t.YourColumn,SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.YourColumn,' ',1),''))
```

For SQL-Server use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET t.yourColumn = SUBSTRING(t.YourColumn,CHARINDEX(t.YourColumn,' ') + 1,100)
```

Comment: sorry - and you must also CONCAT the reult with a space CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column,' ',1),' '); to remove the fist space

Comment: Yes, correct, fixed using `LTRIM` :) @BerndBuffen .

Comment: Ehm.. I'm using 2014 SQL mgmt studio and I'm getting the following
'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Its SQL-Server or MySQL ?? @Angie

Answer (score 0):

SELECT substr(data FROM position(' ' in data)+1) FROM test.randomdata;

UPDATE test.randomdata SET data=substr(data FROM position(' ' in data)+1);

position+1 preserve strings without spaces ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE `tabl1` SET `col1` = TRIM(REPLACE("NSW New South Wales","NSW", "")) WHERE `col1` LIKE 'NSW%'
```

Or this:

```
UPDATE  `tabl1` `t`
  SET `t`.`col1` = TRIM(
    REPLACE(
      `t`.`col1`,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(`t`.`col1`, ' ', 1),
      ""
    )
  )
WHERE LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`t`.`col1`, ' ', 1)) <= 3
```

Comment: Sorry but this replaces only the current data, I'm trying to replace every abbreviation up to max 3 char lengths until the first space that is encountered on the same field.

Comment: @Angie I updated my answer.I do not do for the sake of evaluation.The main thing help people to resolve his problem.
Maybe someone else will need my answer :)

Comment: Thanks :) Tried this as well for the sake of sanity and it does work.